# How do I adjust non text editor font sizes in Vscode

Tags: text, fonts, visual-studio-code

How do I change the font sizes of the text inside the ui items and text fields in Vscode?

See the image for areas of interest. I want to resize all the text you see in the pic.

[image: vscode]

Comment: Use   "window.zoomLevel": 1, (some number there)
 together with   "editor.fontSize": 14,
to get to a comfortable combination of editor font size and ui element fontsize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the Font Size field shown in your screen shot will only change the font within the editor, not the text for other elements of VS Code. You can try adjusting the zoom setting:

1. CTRL + SHIFT + P
2. Type 'zoom'
3. Select "View: Zoom In"

[image]

This will zoom in the entire IDE, not just the editor. This will make the font size bigger of the IDE since it's being zoomed in. I don't believe there's any setting to specifically change the font size of the text in non editor elements of the IDE so I think this is the best "work around" to solve your request. Try it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: thanks, zooming seems to work except for the top menu bar, (the gray bar in the screen)

Comment: it is funny but after my post one of the newest VScode updates actually started zooming the menu fonts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Gear icon on bottom left and choose 'Settings' OR "Ctrl+,"
Then type "Font" in the search bar of settings page. Font Size option will appear